# Modifying the OverviewMapComponent.mxml

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer, flex-2.5

In the flexviewer I want to add text in the overview map that says "overview map."
I am not sure what the code would be and assume it would be place in the s:BorderContainer  component?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.events.EffectEvent;

        private const lineSym:SimpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol("solid", 0xFF0000, 0.7, 2);
        private const currentExtentSym:SimpleFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol("solid", 0xFF0000, 0.2, lineSym);

        [Bindable]
        public var map:Map;
        public var configData:ConfigData;
        public var openDefaultToolTip:String;
        public var closeDefaultToolTip:String;

        private var graphicsLayer:GraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        private var proxyUrl:String;
        private var overviewGraphic:Graphic = new Graphic();
        private var useBaseMapLayer:Boolean;
        private var baseMapSwitched:Boolean;
        private var currentBaseMapId:String;
        private var hasOverviewGraphicBeenMoved:Boolean = false;
        private var xOffset:Number;
        private var yOffset:Number;

        [Bindable]
        private var openToolTip:String;
        [Bindable]
        private var closeToolTip:String;

        private function init():void
        {
            overviewGraphic.buttonMode = true;
            toggleIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleIcon_clickHandler);
            viewBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.getStyle("backgroundColor"));
        }

        private function toggleIcon_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            currentState = (currentState == "collapsed") ? "expanded" : "collapsed";
        }

        private var _configXML:XML;

        public function set expansionDirection(direction:String):void
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case ExpansionDirection.UP_RIGHT:
                {
                    toggleIcon.rotation = 90;
                    toggleIcon.left = toggleIcon.bottom = iconMask.left = iconMask.bottom = null;
                    toggleIcon.right = toggleIcon.top = iconMask.right = iconMask.top = 0;
                    break;
                }
                case ExpansionDirection.DOWN_RIGHT:
                {
                    toggleIcon.rotation = 180;
                    toggleIcon.left = toggleIcon.top = iconMask.left = iconMask.top = null;
                    toggleIcon.right = toggleIcon.bottom = iconMask.right = iconMask.bottom = 0;
                    break;
                }
                case ExpansionDirection.DOWN_LEFT:
                {
                    toggleIcon.rotation = 270;
                    toggleIcon.right = toggleIcon.top = iconMask.right = iconMask.top = null;
                    toggleIcon.left = toggleIcon.bottom = iconMask.left = iconMask.bottom = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public function get configXML():XML
        {
            return _configXML;
        }

        public function set configXML(value:XML):void
        {
            _configXML = value;

            if (configXML)
            {
                // overviewmap open/close tooltip label
                openToolTip = configXML.labels.opentooltip || openDefaultToolTip;
                closeToolTip = configXML.labels.closetooltip || closeDefaultToolTip;

                // proxyURL
                proxyUrl = configData.proxyUrl;

                var url:String = configXML.layer.@url;
                var type:String;
                var useProxy:Boolean;
                if (url)
                {
                    useBaseMapLayer = false;
                    type = configXML.layer.@type;
                    useProxy = configXML.layer.@useproxy[0] && configXML.layer.@useproxy == "true";
                    switch (type.toLowerCase())
                    {
                        case "tiled":
                        {
                            var tiledlayer:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(url);
                            tiledlayer.alpha = alpha;
                            if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                            {
                                tiledLayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                            }
                            overviewMap.addLayer(tiledlayer);
                            break;
                        }
                        case "dynamic":
                        {
                            var dynlayer:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url);
                            dynlayer.alpha = alpha;
                            if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                            {
                                dynlayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                            }
                            overviewMap.addLayer(dynlayer);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    useBaseMapLayer = true;
                    // get the base map layers
                    for (var i:uint = 0; i < configData.basemaps.length; i++)
                    {
                        type = configData.basemaps[i].type;
                        useProxy = configData.basemaps[i].useProxy;
                        proxyUrl = configData.proxyUrl;

                        const alpha:Number = Number(configData.basemaps[i].alpha);
                        const autoRefresh:Number = Number(configData.basemaps[i].autoRefresh);
                        const label:String = configData.basemaps[i].label;
                        const token:String = configData.basemaps[i].token;
                        const urlBaseMap:String = configData.basemaps[i].url;
                        const bingMapKey:String = configData.basemaps[i].key;
                        const style:String = configData.basemaps[i].style;
                        const visible:Boolean = configData.basemaps[i].visible;
                        const visibleLayers:String = configData.basemaps[i].visibleLayers;
                        const culture:String = configData.basemaps[i].culture;
                        const useamf:Boolean = configData.basemaps[i].useamf;
                        const mode:String = configData.basemaps[i].mode;
                        const noData:Number = Number(configData.basemaps[i].noData);
                        const serviceHost:String = configData.basemaps[i].serviceHost;
                        const serviceName:String = configData.basemaps[i].serviceName;
                        const definitionExpression:String = configData.basemaps[i].definitionExpression;

                        switch (type.toLowerCase())
                        {
                            case "tiled":
                            {
                                var tiledLayer:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(urlBaseMap);
                                tiledLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                tiledLayer.id = label;
                                tiledLayer.visible = visible;
                                tiledLayer.token = token;
                                if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                                {
                                    tiledLayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                                }
                                overviewMap.addLayer(tiledLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                            case "dynamic":
                            {
                                var dynLayer:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(urlBaseMap);
                                dynLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                dynLayer.id = label;
                                dynLayer.visible = visible;
                                dynLayer.token = token;
                                if (autoRefresh > 0)
                                {
                                    setInterval(dynLayer.refresh, autoRefresh * 1000);
                                }
                                if (visibleLayers)
                                {
                                    var vizLayers:Array = visibleLayers.split(",");
                                    dynLayer.visibleLayers = new ArrayCollection(vizLayers);
                                }
                                if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                                {
                                    dynLayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                                }
                                overviewMap.addLayer(dynLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                            case "feature":
                            {
                                var featureLayer:FeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer(urlBaseMap);
                                featureLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                featureLayer.id = label;
                                featureLayer.visible = visible;
                                featureLayer.outFields = [ '*' ];
                                featureLayer.token = token;
                                featureLayer.useAMF = useamf;
                                if (mode)
                                {
                                    featureLayer.mode = mode;
                                }
                                if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                                {
                                    featureLayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                                }
                                if (definitionExpression && definitionExpression != "")
                                {
                                    featureLayer.definitionExpression = definitionExpression;
                                }
                                overviewMap.addLayer(featureLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                            case "bing":
                            {
                                var veTiledLayer:VETiledLayer = new VETiledLayer();
                                veTiledLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                veTiledLayer.id = label;
                                veTiledLayer.visible = visible;
                                veTiledLayer.key = bingMapKey;
                                if (style)
                                {
                                    veTiledLayer.mapStyle = style;
                                }
                                if (culture)
                                {
                                    veTiledLayer.culture = culture;
                                }
                                overviewMap.addLayer(veTiledLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                            case "image":
                            {
                                var imgLayer:ArcGISImageServiceLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer(urlBaseMap);
                                imgLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                imgLayer.id = label;
                                imgLayer.visible = visible;
                                imgLayer.noData = noData;
                                imgLayer.token = token;
                                if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                                {
                                    imgLayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                                }
                                overviewMap.addLayer(imgLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                            case "arcims":
                            {
                                var arcimsLayer:ArcIMSMapServiceLayer = new ArcIMSMapServiceLayer();
                                arcimsLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                arcimsLayer.id = label;
                                arcimsLayer.visible = visible;
                                arcimsLayer.serviceHost = serviceHost;
                                arcimsLayer.serviceName = serviceName;
                                if (autoRefresh > 0)
                                {
                                    setInterval(arcimsLayer.refresh, autoRefresh * 1000);
                                }
                                if (visibleLayers)
                                {
                                    var visLayers:Array = visibleLayers.split(",");
                                    arcimsLayer.visibleLayers = new ArrayCollection(visLayers);
                                }
                                if (proxyUrl && useProxy)
                                {
                                    arcimsLayer.proxyURL = proxyUrl;
                                }
                                overviewMap.addLayer(arcimsLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                            case "osm":
                            {
                                var osmLayer:OpenStreetMapLayer = new OpenStreetMapLayer();
                                osmLayer.alpha = alpha;
                                osmLayer.id = label;
                                osmLayer.name = label;
                                osmLayer.visible = visible;
                                overviewMap.addLayer(osmLayer);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    AppEvent.addListener(AppEvent.BASEMAP_SWITCH, viewContainer_basemapSwitchHandler);
                }
                currentState = configXML.initialstate == "open" ? "expanded" : "collapsed";
                if (currentState == "collapsed") // turn layer(s) off if component is collapsed
                {
                    for each (var layer:Layer in overviewMap.layers)
                    {
                        layer.visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function updateOverviewExtentFromMap():void
        {
            overviewMap.extent = map.extent.expand(3);
            overviewGraphic.geometry = map.extent;
        }

        private function updateMapExtentFromOverview():void
        {
            map.extent = overviewGraphic.geometry as Extent;
        }

        private function map_extentChangeHandler(event:ExtentEvent):void
        {
            updateOverviewExtentFromMap();

            //hide overview box if larger than overview map
            if (!overviewMap.extent.contains(overviewGraphic.geometry))
            {
                overviewGraphic.visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                overviewGraphic.visible = true;
            }
        }

        private function overviewMap_loadHandler(event:MapEvent):void
        {
            graphicsLayer.name = "overviewMapGraphicsLayer";
            graphicsLayer.symbol = currentExtentSym;
            overviewMap.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

            overviewGraphic.geometry = map.extent;
            overviewGraphic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, overviewGraphic_mouseDownHandler);

            //update map extent when mouse moves out of the overview map
            overviewMap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, overviewMap_mouseRollOutHandler);

            graphicsLayer.add(overviewGraphic);

            map.addEventListener(ExtentEvent.EXTENT_CHANGE, map_extentChangeHandler);
            updateOverviewExtentFromMap();
        }

        private function overviewMap_mouseRollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            overviewMap.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, overviewMap_mouseMoveHandler);
            overviewMap.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, overviewMap_mouseUpHandler);
            overviewGraphic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, overviewGraphic_mouseDownHandler);

            if (hasOverviewGraphicBeenMoved)
            {
                hasOverviewGraphicBeenMoved = false;
                updateMapExtentFromOverview();
            }
        }

        private function overviewGraphic_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            overviewGraphic.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, overviewGraphic_mouseDownHandler);
            overviewMap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, overviewMap_mouseUpHandler);
            overviewMap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, overviewMap_mouseMoveHandler);

            var overviewCenterMapPoint:MapPoint = overviewGraphic.geometry.extent.center;
            var mouseMapPoint:MapPoint = overviewMap.toMapFromStage(event.stageX, event.stageY);
            xOffset = mouseMapPoint.x - overviewCenterMapPoint.x;
            yOffset = mouseMapPoint.y - overviewCenterMapPoint.y;
        }

        private function overviewMap_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            hasOverviewGraphicBeenMoved = true;

            var overviewExtent:Extent = overviewGraphic.geometry as Extent;
            var mouseMapPoint:MapPoint = overviewMap.toMapFromStage(event.stageX, event.stageY);
            mouseMapPoint.x -= xOffset;
            mouseMapPoint.y -= yOffset;

            overviewGraphic.geometry = overviewExtent.centerAt(mouseMapPoint);
        }

        private function overviewMap_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            overviewMap.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, overviewMap_mouseMoveHandler);
            overviewMap.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, overviewMap_mouseUpHandler);
            overviewGraphic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, overviewGraphic_mouseDownHandler);

            if (hasOverviewGraphicBeenMoved)
            {
                hasOverviewGraphicBeenMoved = false;
                updateMapExtentFromOverview();
            }
        }

        private function viewContainer_basemapSwitchHandler(event:AppEvent):void
        {
            baseMapSwitched = true;
            currentBaseMapId = event.data as String;
            if (currentState == "expanded")
            {
                showCurrentBaseMap(currentBaseMapId);
            }
        }

        private function showCurrentBaseMap(currentBaseMapId:String):void
        {
            var configBasemaps:Array = configData.basemaps;

            if (currentBaseMapId)
            {
                var selectedLabel:String;
                for (var i:uint = 0; i < configBasemaps.length; i++)
                {
                    if (configBasemaps[i].id == currentBaseMapId)
                    {
                        selectedLabel = configBasemaps[i].label;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (selectedLabel)
                {
                    // turn on the selected basemap layers (more than one layer can have the same label)
                    var layers:ArrayCollection = overviewMap.layers as ArrayCollection;
                    for (i = 0; i < configBasemaps.length; i++)
                    {
                        var basemapLabel:String = configBasemaps[i].label;
                        for each (var layer:Layer in layers)
                        {
                            if (layer.id == basemapLabel)
                            {
                                if (layer.id == selectedLabel)
                                {
                                    layer.visible = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    layer.visible = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function sequence_effectStartHandler(event:EffectEvent):void
        {
            if (currentState == "expanded")
            {
                if (useBaseMapLayer)
                {
                    if (baseMapSwitched)
                    {
                        showCurrentBaseMap(currentBaseMapId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // on start up and if basemap is not switched
                        for (var i:int = 0; i < configData.basemaps.length; i++)
                        {
                            var basemapLabel:String = configData.basemaps[i].label;
                            var isVisible:Boolean = configData.basemaps[i].visible;
                            for each (var layer:Layer in overviewMap.layers)
                            {
                                if (layer.id == basemapLabel)
                                {
                                    layer.visible = isVisible;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for each (var layer1:Layer in overviewMap.layers)
                    {
                        layer1.visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function sequence_effectEndHandler(event:EffectEvent):void
        {
            if (currentState == "collapsed") // turn layer(s) off if component is collapsed
            {
                for each (var layer:Layer in overviewMap.layers)
                {
                    if (!(layer is GraphicsLayer && layer.name == "overviewMapGraphicsLayer"))
                    {
                        layer.visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="collapsed"/>
    <s:State name="expanded"/>
</s:states>

<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="*" toState="*">
        <s:Sequence effectEnd="sequence_effectEndHandler(event)" effectStart="sequence_effectStartHandler(event)">
            <s:Resize duration="800" target="{viewBox}"/>
            <s:Rotate angleBy="180"
                      autoCenterTransform="true"
                      duration="300"
                      target="{toggleIcon}"/>
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>

<s:BorderContainer id="viewBox"
                   width.collapsed="{toggleIcon.width}" width.expanded="250" height.collapsed="{toggleIcon.height}" height.expanded="250"
                   backgroundAlpha="1.0">
    <esri:Map id="overviewMap"
              width="250" height="250"
              clickRecenterEnabled="false"
              doubleClickZoomEnabled="false"
              keyboardNavigationEnabled="false"
              load="overviewMap_loadHandler(event)"
              logoVisible="false"
              mask="{mapMask}"
              panArrowsVisible="false"
              panEnabled="false"
              rubberbandZoomEnabled="false"
              scaleBarVisible="false"
              scrollWheelZoomEnabled="false"
              wrapAround180="{map.wrapAround180}"
              zoomSliderVisible="false"/>
    <s:BorderContainer id="mapMask"
                       width="{viewBox.width}" height="{viewBox.height}"/>
    <s:Group width="{viewBox.width}" height="{viewBox.height}">
        <mx:Image id="toggleIcon"
                  width="23" height="23"
                  buttonMode="true"
                  mask="{iconMask}"
                  smoothBitmapContent="true"
                  source="assets/images/i_expand2.png"
                  toolTip.collapsed="{openToolTip}"
                  toolTip.expanded="{closeToolTip}"
                  useHandCursor="true"/>
        <s:BorderContainer id="iconMask"
                           width="{toggleIcon.width}" height="{toggleIcon.height}"/>
    </s:Group>

</s:BorderContainer>
<s:Rect left="-1" right="-1" top="-1" bottom="-1">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="{getStyle('contentBackgroundColor')}" weight="1"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
<s:Rect left="-5" right="-5" top="-5" bottom="-5">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="{getStyle('color')}" weight="2"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you would do it.

```
<esri:Map id="overviewMap"
              width="250" height="250"
              clickRecenterEnabled="false"
              doubleClickZoomEnabled="false"
              keyboardNavigationEnabled="false"
              load="overviewMap_loadHandler(event)"
              logoVisible="false"
              mask="{mapMask}"
              panArrowsVisible="false"
              panEnabled="false"
              rubberbandZoomEnabled="false"
              scaleBarVisible="false"
              scrollWheelZoomEnabled="false"
              wrapAround180="{map.wrapAround180}"
              zoomSliderVisible="false"/>
    <s:Label includeIn="expanded" x="95" y="10" width="85" height="16" backgroundColor="#0A0A0A"
             color="#FFD700" fontSize="12" fontWeight="bold" paddingBottom="2" paddingLeft="2"
             paddingRight="2" paddingTop="2" text="Overview Map"/>
```